# Automatic scrolling on windows menu - Windows 10

Tags: windows, mouse

My computer has started to scroll non-stop on the windows run menu. So when I hit the windows key it cycles through the options. I'm using Windows 10. It does this even if I disconnect the keyboard and mouse. Using a different mouse didn't fix it.

The only thing that fixes it is to sign out and then sign in again. However I need to do this each time I boot my computer. Is there a better fix?

Comment: So when I hit the windows key it cycles through the options.    .......   Try running DISM / SFC and see if the initial repair fixes it.    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Currently it may have fixed itself!  I did nothing.

Comment: Hmm, now the problem is back.

Comment: Try the DISM / SFC steps to see if that fixes the issue

Comment: I tried that. It found some stuff. I didn't check the log. Unfortunately it didn't fix the problem.  Each time I reboot, I need to sign out and that fixes it until I reboot again.

Comment: Try a Windows 10 Repair Install (Media Creation Link) and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tentatively fixed it by removing my Logitech game controller (Gamepad F310). Perhaps, despite having great reviews and being a very common device, it had a conflict with the keyboard and/or mouse.

Comment: On the contrary, the controller is not to blame. The problem is rather with many UWP applications accepting game controller input, a rather unexpected feature for desktop software.

Comment: Pretty sure I'm getting the same problem with an XBox Wireless controller. Seems fine until I turn it on the controller, and then sometimes I get the constant scrolling up. Turning off the controller doesn't always fix the problem either. Incredibly annoying bug.